# add class file using umbraco

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, umbraco

i have a login page named test.ascx and also a test.ascx.cs.in the web config i set a database.i have problem when conneting to database.i write all the connetion oriented codes in a class file named test.cs.how can i add this class file in umbraco.

ascx code is

```
<div style="border:solid 1px red;margin:50px 0px 0px 400px;width:275px; height: 98px;
text-align:center;">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtpass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>

</div>
```

Comment: What problem do you have?

Why do you use a login page - what do you want to accomplish?

Note: Umbraco has backend users and frontend users (members).

max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a usercontrol into umbraco by using macro. For this you have to create a web project and have to add its dll to your umbraco bin folder. If you have class files then by adding this dll you can use that class also.

you have to add the ascx files into usercontrol folder and have to create a macro using this usercontrol.

Please check the [link](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/introduction-to-umbraco/developer-introduction/using-net-user-controls)

Comment: its not css class.its (.cs) class.it will not get by adding dll.i tried...any way thanks for ur response friend

Comment: do you created the web project? if it is web project you got dlls to your project and you have to add those dlls to the bin folder.